# How to delete one item from recyclerView?

Tags: android, database, android-recyclerview

I have a database in my app and show it in a recyclerView .

In each item of recyclerView I have an ImageView for delete item.

I want to click on imageView and delete item from database and recyclerView.

this is mayAdapter:

```
public class ShoppingCartAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ShoppingCartAdapter.ShoppingCartViewHolder>{


private final Context context;
private final List<DataModelListShoppingCart> shoppingCartList;
private ShopDatabaseOpenHelper openHelper;

public ShoppingCartAdapter(Context context, List<DataModelListShoppingCart> shoppingCartList, ShopDatabaseOpenHelper openHelper){


    this.context = context;
    this.shoppingCartList = shoppingCartList;
    this.openHelper = openHelper;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ShoppingCartAdapter.ShoppingCartViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.model_shopping_cart_layout,parent,false);
    return new ShoppingCartAdapter.ShoppingCartViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ShoppingCartAdapter.ShoppingCartViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final DataModelListShoppingCart shoppingCart = shoppingCartList.get(position);


    holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openHelper.deleteProduct(shoppingCart.getId());
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    });

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return shoppingCartList.size();
}


 public class ShoppingCartViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageView delete;

    public ShoppingCartViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        delete = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_view_clear_shopping_cart);
    }

    }
}
```

I set OnClickListener for imageView and delete the item from database but item still here. When I back to Activity item deleted .

How to delete item as soon as I click on image view ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you must delete item from your data source too (your `shoppingCartList` here).
If you get per item in binding holder(onBindViewHolder) from db, your way will be correct.

Answer (score 3):

Just remove that item from list too.

```
holder.delete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openHelper.deleteProduct(shoppingCart.getId());
            shoppingCartList.remove(position);
            notifyItemRemoved(position);
        }
    });
```

Comment: shoppingCartList.remove(position); this code just remove one item and for other item not working. because 'position' has changed.

Comment: I think both answers are same, aren't they?and mine one is older too.

Comment: shoppingCartList.remove(position); this line didn't work. you should change 'position' to 'shoppingCart' .

Comment: Okay,I should've also just given the hint to remove data from List only.

Comment: Using position should have worked, I'll check later, thanks for pointing.